# Is it possible to have local Git branches working with remote SVN repositories?

Tags: git, svn

We have a SVN repository with our source code. We really want to use local Git branches to develop new features and take advantage of Git capabilities like the merging algorithms.

Is that possible? If yes, could someone provide some information about how to perform that?

Comment: So this remote SVN repository would merely be a "backup and distribution method"?

Comment: Not really. After we develop a feature on a local Git branch we are going to merge into the remote SVN repository. (if it is possible)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. You will need to use [git-svn](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html).

First you will need to `git svn clone` your SVN repository.  Note that this will fetch *every revision* from the SVN server, and recreate the history as a Git repository.  **These Git repositories should not be shared by multiple developers.** Each developer should run `git svn clone` individually!

Then you can create local branches all you want using standard Git commands, since you basically have a standard Git repository with some extra SVN metadata for tracking SVN commits.  You can use commands like `git svn dcommit` to push commits in Git to the SVN server (each Git commit would become a separate SVN commit).

I would consider reading a good [git-svn tutorial](http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial).

(If possible, you might also consider whether you would actually rather use git-svn to convert your SVN repository to a Git repository, and then discontinue use of SVN altogether.)

Comment: So, can I perform local commits and when I want to push them into the SVN repository, I perform a dcommit?

Comment: @gustavodidomenico Correct.  If you are on a branch being tracked by git-svn, the dcommit operation will perform a batch of SVN commits and will *rewrite* your local Git commits with metadata about the SVN commits.  (So things can get a bit wonky.  If you understand what a rebase does or what filter-branch can do, that's what will happen to your local Git repo every time you `git svn dcommit`.  This is one of the reasons multiple developers should not share the Git repo in any way.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm going to check the tutorials.